# Windows batch with FOR and IF EXIST and GOTO issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, exists

Ok, so i'm writing a batch file to help client migration by replacing a file on a client.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Only type "clients" or "servers"
SET /P TYPE=clients or servers:
SET /P LIST=%TYPE% list filename:
SET /P SITE=Site:
SET SYMPATH=""
SET LIST2=""
SET N=
SET N2=0
Echo This will migrate %TYPE% in site %SITE% from list %LIST%, correct?
PAUSE
:STRT
SET /a N2=N2+1
SET LIST2=%LIST%%N%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v IN (%LIST2%) DO (
ECHO Checking %%v...
SET COMP=%%v
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files (x86)\symantec\symantec endpoint protection\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files (x86)\symantec\symantec endpoint protection" & CALL :MIGRATE
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files\symantec\symantec endpoint protection\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files\symantec\symantec endpoint protection" & CALL :MIGRATE
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files (x86)\symantec antivirus\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files (x86)\symantec antivirus" & CALL :MIGRATE
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files\symantec antivirus\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files\symantec antivirus" & CALL :MIGRATE
ECHO Could not find SEP on client %%v
ECHO %%v >> %LIST%%N2%
)
:MIGRATE
ECHO Migrating %COMP%...
psexec \\%COMP% -h "c:\%SYMPATH%\smc.exe" -p xxxxxx -stop
copy "%TYPE%_xml\My Company_Workplace_%TYPE%_%SITE%_sylink.xml" "\\%COMP%\c$\%SYMPATH%\SyLink.xml" /Y
psexec \\%COMP% -h "c:\%SYMPATH%\smc.exe" -start
ECHO Migrated %COMP% to SEP12 group %SITE% >> END_%SITE%.log
ECHO Migrated %COMP% to SEP12 group %SITE%
EXIT /b
SET /a N=N+1
ECHO End of the list, starting over with %LIST2%
GOTO STRT `
```

Most things work except that after the client has been migrated it jumps back to the CALL and executes the code:

```
ECHO Could not find SEP on client %%v
ECHO %%v >> %LIST%%N2%
```

This is correct code-wise, however i want it to jump over these 2 lines and continue with the next client, like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Only type "clients" or "servers"
SET /P TYPE=clients or servers:
SET /P LIST=%TYPE% list filename:
SET /P SITE=Site:
SET SYMPATH=""
SET LIST2=""
SET N=
SET N2=0
Echo This will migrate %TYPE% in site %SITE% from list %LIST%, correct?
PAUSE
:STRT
SET /a N2=N2+1
SET LIST2=%LIST%%N%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v IN (%LIST2%) DO (
ECHO Checking %%v...
SET COMP=%%v
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files (x86)\symantec\symantec endpoint protection\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files (x86)\symantec\symantec endpoint protection" & CALL :MIGRATE **& GOTO :NEXT**
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files\symantec\symantec endpoint protection\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files\symantec\symantec endpoint protection" & CALL :MIGRATE **& GOTO :NEXT**
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files (x86)\symantec antivirus\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files (x86)\symantec antivirus" & CALL :MIGRATE **& GOTO :NEXT**
if exist "\\%%v\c$\program files\symantec antivirus\smc.exe" SET "SYMPATH=program files\symantec antivirus" & CALL :MIGRATE **& GOTO :NEXT**
ECHO Could not find SEP on client %%v
ECHO %%v >> %LIST%%N2%
**:NEXT**
)
:MIGRATE
ECHO Migrating %COMP%...
psexec \\%COMP% -h "c:\%SYMPATH%\smc.exe" -p xxxxxx -stop
copy "%TYPE%_xml\My Company_Workplace_%TYPE%_%SITE%_sylink.xml" "\\%COMP%\c$\%SYMPATH%\SyLink.xml" /Y
psexec \\%COMP% -h "c:\%SYMPATH%\smc.exe" -start
ECHO Migrated %COMP% to SEP12 group %SITE% >> END_%SITE%.log
ECHO Migrated %COMP% to SEP12 group %SITE%
EXIT /b
SET /a N=N+1
ECHO End of the list, starting over with %LIST2%
GOTO STRT `
```

But this does not work because i cannot use GOTO and labels in code blocks ( )

So, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v IN (%LIST2%) DO (
    ...
    SET "SYMPATH="
    if exist "\\%%v\c$\..." SET "SYMPATH=..." & CALL :MIGRATE 
    if exist "\\%%v\c$\..." SET "SYMPATH=..." & CALL :MIGRATE 
    if exist "\\%%v\c$\..." SET "SYMPATH=..." & CALL :MIGRATE 
    if exist "\\%%v\c$\..." SET "SYMPATH=..." & CALL :MIGRATE 

    if not defined SYMPATH (
        ECHO Could not find SEP on client %%v
        ECHO %%v >> %LIST%%N2%
    )
)
```

For each iteration reset `sympath` and do the tests. If at the end the variable has not been defined, no match has been found.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%v IN (%LIST2%) do (
  echo Checking %%v...
  set "COMP=%%~v"
  set "SYMPATH="
  for %%P in (
    "program files (x86)\symantec\symantec endpoint protection"
    "program files\symantec\symantec endpoint protection"
    "program files (x86)\symantec antivirus\smc.exe"
    "program files\symantec antivirus"
  ) do if not defined SYMPATH if exist "\\%%v\c$\%%~P" (
    set "SYMPATH=%%~p"
    call :MIGRATE
  )
  if not defined SYMPATH (
    echo Could not find SEP on client %%v
    echo %%v >> %LIST%%N2%
  )
)
```